# Flask Expandable URLs That Work At Each Variable Stage

Tags: python, web-services, google-chrome, web-applications, flask

Have tried several hours to accomplish this with Python 2.7s Flask:

```
site.com/diseases                     : gives a page where I can list all diseases
site.com/diseases/diseaseX            : list of subtopics for diseaseX
site.com/diseases/diseaseX/subHeading : so a url can be shared that brings users to a specific subheading e.g. overview, causes
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/home')
def home(): render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/diseases/<disease>/<subheading>')
def diseases(disease=None, subheading=None):
    return render_template('diseases.html', disease='new')

app.run(debug=True)
```

The route needs both variable or gives a 404 Error.  The argument defaults were changed to 'disease' & 'sub', but loading site.com/diseases gives 404 also.  Only adding variables e.g. site.com/diseases/diabetes/treatment works, but then what if someone types just site.com/diseases or site.com/diseases/diabetes?  I couldn't find examples of anyone doing this, everyone was just stating the required variables, then obeying them, so maybe this is a problem of not understanding standard web app procedures.  Ideally the URLs will be expandable to any length e.g. /diseases/diabetes/treatment/treatmentX, but I'm somewhat lost as to how.

EDIT
I've made progress by doing

```
@app.route('/diseases/<path:queries>)
```

The path: element treats any / as text, so I can now do

```
/diseases/diabetes/treatment/treatmentX
```

and in the function do

```
queries.split('/')
```

to get the discrete URL parts.  This seems a little long winded, but maybe it's how things are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiple routes to the same function and set defaults in the route definition. Here is my suggestion:

```
@app.route('/diseases', defaults={'disease': None, 'subheading': None})
@app.route('/diseases/<str:disease>/<str:subheading>')
def diseases(disease, subheading):
    return render_template('diseases.html', disease='new')
```